# Swazoo REST test server

Tags: smalltalk

I would like to use Swazoo to write a simple REST test server. When the server receives a request, some dialog shows it to the user and they provide a response.
I subclassed SwazooResource and make sure a request to the server always gets a resource of this type. This class overrides answerTo:

```
answerTo: aRequest

    ^self createOkResponseWithContents: (Dialog request: 'Please provide a response')
```

This however makes the Swazoo server return a 500 response, since all exceptions are catched and handled in Swazoo.HTTPConnection>>produceResponseFor:

Any hints on how to achieve this?

Comment: Start adding 'self halt' in exception blocks to override default exception handling. You should also add your own exception handler into #answerTo: to catch errors from your code

Comment: Thanks, if you post this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score -1):

Is there a special reason not to use the [Seaside-REST](http://www.squeaksource.com/Seaside31Addons) stuff?

[edit] Why the -1?

Comment: I did not vote your answer down, but to answer your question: I have to build on code that already exists.